# File field has empty value on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In a rails application, I have a form with a file field, that uploads an image. On a create action everything is fine, and the record appears in the DB. But on the update, if I just submit the form without changes, a validation error occurs. It says that an image should be present. If I turn off the validation, it updates the record, but without an image. I can't get, why my file field has an empty value. Here is my form:

```
<%= form_with(model: [:admin, @menu_image], local: true) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/admin/error-messages', object: @menu_image %>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= f.file_field :source %>
         <%= f.hidden_field :source_cache %>

         <%= image_tag(f.object.source.url, style: 'width: 200px; vertical-align: top') if f.object.source? %>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.submit t('admin.actions.submit'), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is my parameters hash:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3NdtBlFrJYQBTR25qLRwIZvPzFNcTDUZv3JIzyORZ+sP/VfbO2eymp563mLDFmePhLDWRrynaKnmKgyvyeIHZg==", "menu_image"=>{"source_cache"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"2"}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see happening when you submit your form without changing anything?

Comment: For example, if I had a title, and I update only a title field, the image should stay the same, and only the title will change

Comment: That makes sense, would you please update with your controller action for update?

Comment: Can you show your update controller action and the permitted params?

Comment: I have found how to fix it, but I don't understand why does it happen. In my edit action, I had to add `@menu_image.source.cache!`

Comment: It was v2.0.0 of `carrierwave`. v1.3.1 works as expected.